# Regex for Url rewriting not working

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm doing some URL rewriting but it's not working.

I'd like to change `/site_artisans/site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php` to `/site_artisans/site_artisans/peintre-annecy.php` (slash added just after site_artisans).

my code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site_artisans$ /site_artisans/ [L]
```

Edit :

I realized maybe I'm not being very articulate :

the actual name of the file is C:\wamp\www\site_artisans\site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php (http://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php) and what I'd like is to have the adress http://localhost/site_artisans/site_artisans/peintre-annecy.php displayed instead of the first one.

Comment: can you post the error from your apache logfile?

Comment: @aeby I restarted Wamp and no I've got no error message displayed but nothing happens too.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site_artisans(.+)$ /site_artisans/$1 [L]
```

---

I suspect the above code is not going to work on the local server. Try this for the local server:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^site_artisans/site_artisans(.+)$ /site_artisans/site_artisans/$1 [L]
```

Comment: For your first answer I get : Not Found

The requested URL /site_artisans/peintre-annecy.php was not found on this server.

Comment: @Bruno: Try the second example, I suspected it wouldn't work on your local server. That's why I added the second solution. You should consider aliasing your local projects so there is no difference between your development and production environments.

Comment: Your second answer does nothing. (But thanks for trying ! ;-) )

Comment: @Bruno: Updated the regex, try that. If it still doesn't work, then you are probably doing something wrong. Or the `.htaccess` file is not in the right place.

Comment: It still doesn't work. You might be right : maybe there's something wrong somewhere else. The .htaccess file is in the folder of the website (C:\wamp\www\site_artisans).

Answer (score 0):

Place this .htaccess in your web root of your wamp setup:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/site_artisans/site_artisans/([a-zA-Z0-9-_%]+.php)$ /site_artisans/site_artisans$1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is going to be a ton of different urls so my regexp needs to accept them.

Comment: Oh. You didn't mention that before. Let me update my snippet.

Comment: What is the physical name and location of the file on the server that you wish to rewrite to?

Comment: C:\wamp\www\site_artisans\site_artisanspeintre-annecy.php

Comment: @Bruno I have it backwards, then. Let me fix that.